# Fancytip is not working

Tags: jquery, html

Why is my fancytip not working? It should be when the mouse hovers the image the popup will show.[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d0qtycwj/)

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#qm1').fancytip({
        popupside: 'right',
        text: 'Test popup to right of content.',
        voffsetpx: '6',
        hoffsetpx: '5'
    });
});
```

**html**

```
<img id="qm1" src="images/WebResource.png" style="padding-left: 5px;" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You not correct include jquery.fancytip.js, try with this url `https://balrog.googlecode.com/svn-history/r34/trunk/views/js/jquery.fancytip.js`

http://jsfiddle.net/d0qtycwj/4/

Comment: @Jennifer I think for this tooltips style set in js file, look here https://code.google.com/p/balrog/source/browse/trunk/views/js/jquery.fancytip.js?r=34 Why selected old plugin? You can find better, like this http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/ or http://qtip2.com/ look at them.

Answer (score 1):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d0qtycwj/5/)

You didn't include the correct script file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#qm1').fancytip({
        popupside: 'right',
        text: 'Test popup to right of content.',
        voffsetpx: '6',
        hoffsetpx: '5'
    });
});
```

get your script file from:
http://www.game-point.net/misc/jquery/fancytip/jquery.fancytip.js

And check the jsfiddle up top to see it in action